# Is this a valid pdf? Continuous r.v. with "weird" pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

> The pdf of a continuous random variable is given by:

$$ f_X(x) = 1/3,~ 0 < x < 1 $$
$$ f_X(x) = 2/3,~ 1 < x < 2 $$
$$ f_X(x) = 0,~ \text{otherwise} $$

My problem with this continuous random variable is that its density has jump discontinuities at $x = 0, x = 1$, and $x = 2$. I know that pdfs can be defined as piecewise functions, but from what I've seen so far (in the two probability courses I have taken at university and a variety of video lectures), pdfs defined as piecewise functions always have endpoints that meet, in order to form a continuous function.

Finally, the question I have is: **is this a valid pdf?**

Comment: No problem. Even the $\text{cdf}$ may have discontinuities.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How? I can see in any textbook that the cdf of a continuous r.v. is a continuous function

Comment: You are right, this occurs with discrete r.v.'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this PDF is a valid density function. A random variable is considered to be continuous if its cumulative distribution function (CDF) is everywhere continuous. There is no other requirement; for example we don't require the density to be continuous.

Think of the uniform $[0,1]$ distribution. It is a continuous RV since its CDF
$$
F(x):=\begin{cases} 0&x<0\\ x & 0\le x\le1\\ 1 & x>1\end{cases}
$$
is continuous, yet its density has two jump discontinuities, at $x=0$ and $x=1$.

You can check that the CDF of the density you're looking at is similarly continuous. The CDF will be piecewise linear without jumps:
$$
F(x):=\begin{cases} 0&x<0\\ \frac13x & 0\le x\le1\\\frac13 +\frac23(x-1)&1\le x\le2\\ 1 & x>2\end{cases}
$$
and you can check that differentiating this $F$ will give the density you're looking at.

Comment: The Uniform [0,1] example really helped me, thanks. One question, though: in your $F(x)$, at $x = 1$, $F(x)$ is defined in two different intervals. Is that not a problem?

Comment: @VictorS. Where the intervals overlap the value of $F$ is the same, so there's no problem. At $x=1$ we get $F(1)=\frac13$ either way, and $F(2)=1$ either way. You could adjust the formula to avoid overlap, but as you can see the overlap doesn't lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It has a discontinuity at a point, both RHS and LHS limits exist, so the integrals exist too. To verify the rest, integrate $f$ in each interval.